# Pumping Lemma for CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

So I solved some exercises where I have to use the pumping lemma for contextfree languages but this one is a problem for me:

Consider:

$ L = $  { $w_1£w_2£w_3 \in$ { $0,1,£$}$^*$ | $w_1, w_2, w_3 \in$ {0,1}$^*$ and $\exists i \neq j \in ${$1,2,3$} : $ w_i = w_j$ }.

Show that:  L is ***not*** contextfree.

So L contains words, which are separated with £ and atleast two subwords are the same. My idea is that we create a word ( with the help of the pumping lemma )  that has three different subwords $ w_1, w_2, w_3 $. But I don't find a "start-word". My first idea was to consider z:= 0.....0£0.....0£1.....1. But the problem is this part $ uvwxy = 0.....0£0.....0£1.....1 $ . If I pumped only the 1....1 part,then I wouldnt have a counterexample. So can you please tell me which word is a possible start-word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $L$ allows $w_1$, $w_2$ and $w_3$ to be empty. By chosing one of them to be empty you avoid the problem you have with being able to pump in the "$1\dots 1$ part".

But this is not enough. You cold pump zeroes in both $w_1$ and $w_2$ and thus stay within the language.

For $n$ the constant from the pumping lemma, take for example $$0^n1^n£0^n1^n£.$$

If you want to pump in both $w_1$ and $w_2$, it can only add $1$s to the former  $0$s to the latter destroying the equality.

Comment: Pumping lemmas can be used to prove that a language is **not** context-free and are useless to prove that a language is context-free.

Comment: Right, @J.-E.Pin. And the cited problem statement indeed asks for a proof of context-freeness. But the OP asks for a start word to use the pumping lemma (and have a counterexample). So it seems to me that he really wants to show that the language is not context-free although admittedly he does not state that explicitely.

Comment: I'm so sorry Peter! I meant ***not***  contextfree. And thank you so much for your answer. I'll study it. :)